# "Pointers" in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, reference, nosql

In the project I am currently working on, it seems to make more sense efficiency wise if I create a nested document that contains a list of "pointers" to information stored in other collections. That way this nested document can be easily used to retrieve a list of relevant information. The question is, how to do this? Is there a way to store locations of other information in a field in MongoDB? If not, could anyone suggest a scheme that is equally or more efficient? Thanks very much!

Comment: Store the reference as collection name plus the _id of the referenced record?

Comment: Is there something invalid about this question that warrants a downvote? DBRefs are not exactly ideal for this situation, but using how they work I can create a solution.

Comment: DBRefs are the only option you have.

Comment: Have you thought about embedding those documents that you want to reference?

Answer (score 2):

There is no GOOD way to do this.  If this is what you're looking for, you should be using a relational database.

But if you HAVE to go by this route then, why not store ID's in a document, and then link those ID's to documents in the other collection.

Unfortunately, this would require you to do 2 separate queries, as Mongo does not support compound queries that span documents.